# TypeError: Cannot read property 'url' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, http-get

I am trying to fetch data from a REST API using angular2, everything so far is going fine; however, I have a error that shows on the console only when calling `{{content.img.url}}` it executes fine on the webpage only as it fetch the image url that needs to be fetched and shows the image, but in chrome console it shows:

> EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'url' of undefined in
>   [background-image: url('{{content[img].url}}'); in HomePage@63:29]

I really don't have an idea why it shows the error in the console only! any ideas to solve this?

Below you may find the details of what I am actually doing to fetch the data using the REST API, suggestions of improving the code are welcome!

home.html

```
 <div *ngFor="#content of c1">
 <div class="cards" style="background-image: url('{{content.img.url}}');">
 <div class="txt">{{content.c1Name}}</div></div>
 </div>
```

home.js

```
export class HomePage {
static get parameters(){
return [[Http]];
}

constructor(http) {
this.http = http;
this.c1 = null;
//this is a bad way to do it as _defaultOptions is Protected, is there any way to do it better?
this.http._defaultOptions.headers.append('X-Parse-Application-Id', 'appk');
this.http._defaultOptions.headers.append('X-Parse-REST-API-Key', 'apikey');

this.http.get('https://example.com/classes/table').subscribe(data => {
    this.c1 = data.json().results;
});

}
```

Output of the fetched JSON

```
0:Object
  createdAt:"2016-01-08T13:55:53.558Z"
  c1Name:"Jack"
  img:Object
     __type:"File"
     name:"tfss-6a8bf-1db8-4545-91e6-18-file.jpg"
     url:"http://files.parsetfss.com/f213b50e-dsdsdas-23fsrfdfd-d/file.jpg"
  objectId:"3mfH4sd23"
  updatedAt:"2016-01-08T17:21:00.678Z"
```

Comment: "Fetched JSON" corresponds to the content of the `c1` property?

Comment: @ThierryTemplier yes!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to solve the issue by using the Elvis operator (i.e) in my case I used:

**{{content.img?.url}}**

Hope this helps somebody!

Answer (score 0):

The message tells about `content[img].url` in your message and I can see that you use `content.img.url`. It's really different. I mean the second one accesses the `img` property of the `content` object. The first one the property with the name specified into the `img` variable.

I expect the `content[img]` returns null, especially if `img` is null or undefined. Whereas it's not the case for `content.img`.

Are you sure not to use the expression `content[img]`.

See this plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/IFAuvA36YXelXkUG4HfN?p=preview.

Comment: I've already tried to use content[img].url but got also the same error 
EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'url' of undefined in [background-image: url('{{content[img].url}}'); in HomePage@63:29]

Comment: but what is weird is that content.img.url works fine when fetching the data and getting the url, but the only issue I have, the error that shows on the console!